# Qt5 SSL support

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, network-programming

I am about to make a web api request:

```
QNetworkAccessManager networkManager
QUrlQuery urlQuery;
urlQuery.setQuery("https://lalala.com/login");
urlQuery.addQueryItem("submit", "");
urlQuery.addQueryItem("email", "email@email.com");
urlQuery.addQueryItem("pass", "unbelievable_password");
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(QUrl(urlQuery.query()));

QNetworkReply* reply = networkManager.get(request);

const QString jsonDataString = (QString) reply->readAll();
```

The problem is that I have the following output during execution of this code:

```
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_select_next_proto
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
```

My `.pro`-file contains libs definition: `LIBS += -lcrypto -lssl`, however its existence does not change anything.

Call of `QSslSocket::supportsSsl()` returns `1`.

Execution of `openssl version` returns `OpenSSL 0.9.8za 5 Jun 2014`.

System is `Mac OS X Yosemite`, Qt version is `5.4.0`.

How to make a call to `https` ? Also these errors exists even when I make a call to `http://ip.jsontest.com` which does not need any SSL at all.

Comment: Might be a problem with the server configuration. OpenSSL 0.9 does not have TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2. Your server needs to support TLS 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have to install new version of OpenSSL.